# tableView.scrollToRow behaves differently with a small number of cells | iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to give a tableView and searchBar (tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar) the same behavior as in the Messages and Mail apps i.e. hide the searchBar off the top of the parent view and scroll to show it.

The problem is the search bar is shown/hidden differently when the tableView has a different number of cells. How do I hide the search bar every time?

[Not enough cells to fill the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uVVQ.png)

[Just enough cells to fill the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpwpo.png)

[More than enough cells to fill the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7aaO.png)

The method I'm using is tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)

Comment: Please post some code how you set search bar in header

Comment: tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar (I updated the post as well)